# tilde and double quote keys don't work on the command line

Tags: command-line, server, keyboard

I've just installed Ubuntu Server 11.10 and the tilde (~) and double quotes (") keys don't do anything - they don't print to the screen. I'm only using the command line (no GUI) and many tutorials say to use setxkbmap and xmodmap which aren't working for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check your keyboard layout settings, make sure it's `English (US)` not `English (US, international with dead keys)` (assuming you're using US keyboard).

To change it from the command line, enter the following:

```
$ setxkbmap -layout us
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Sorry about not getting back too soon. I solved the problem via installing/running console-setup and changing the layout from there.

Answer (score 2):

For those not using XWindows, e.g. Ubuntu server, `setxkbmap` won't work.
Use

```
sudo apt-get install console-common
```

Or if it is already installed:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Follow the instructions to set the keyboard, e.g. for me, "pc / qwerty / US american / Standard / Standard".

[Original source is here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758915)

Comment: WARNING: If you are using Xubuntu and installing this console-common it will also remove the xubuntu-desktop package. On the next day when you boot your laptop and you will only see a blank screen and nothing happen..I install again xubuntu-desktop and it works.. I just realize that the console-common is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an international keyboard, try `English US`, with the variant `English (international AltGr dead keys)`, this worked for me. (Whereas `US, alternative international` and `US, international with dead keys` did not work).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the keyboard in the Ubuntu System Settings, Text Entry. Remove the English(UK) from 'Input sources to use:' by selecting it in the list and clicking '-'. (Tested in ubuntu 14.04)

http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Keyboard-Layout-in-Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For US English,
To change it from the command line, enter the following:

```
$ loadkeys us
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue..but fixed it using methods below -

- Permanent Solution: In a Linux dist. OS use the following keyboard layout - "English(US,with euro on 5)"
- Temporary Solution: use the following key combination - 'Alt' + 'Shift' + " "

  or  'Alt'  +  ' '

Hopefully. this will solve your problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with a command `$ setxkbmap -layout us` because for instance in my case, my another keyboard input source (ukrainian) also switched into english, so I did not have kyrillic letters anymore.

So, my suggestion will be simply changing manually *'English (US, alt. intl.)'* into *'English (US)'*.

---

**References:**

- [Keyboard layout not working in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094028/keyboard-layout-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04)