# Keyboard layout not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

I was able to add additional keyboard layout in

> Settings -> Regional & Language -> Input Sources

Bulgarian (new phonetic) to be specific. <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> works fine, the Gnome icon also works fine for switching. The thing is that the layout is the same for English (US) and Bulgarian (new phonetic). Nothing changes if I try to switch, English (US) in both cases.

Any thoughts on this?
I've googled for about 20 minutes, the problems I've found are mostly not able to Super etc. and Gnome icons not working.

Comment: Rebooting may be worth a try.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking the same thing, will try it bit later and will leave a note here, thanks.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, ineed, it is working after restart. "password you entered was incorrect" was my first clue.. ;d, you can post it as answer so I can close this one or I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: Great. Please post the answer yourself. Then, after a couple of days, you'll be able to accept it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is [a 18.04 bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1890875) which is about to be fixed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution was - restarting the system.

Comment: Sometimes restarting the system is not possible. For me, logging out and logging back in worked just fine.

Answer (score 32):

Just for information, if someone is in a similar situation and wants to avoid restarting, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073290/keyboard-layout-switch-issue-in-ubuntu-18-04) worked for me. TL;DR:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 - didn't work for me. What did work was logging out and logging back in.

Comment: DONT DO THIS, it can break your language configuration like for me, and I need to configure it again using UI

Comment: This was enough for me: `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Answer (score 20):

Reloading Gnome after changing the keyboard language also works, which is less "destructive" than than logging out or restarting:

`ALT + F2` to bring up the command box, `r` and `Enter` to reload.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Using Linux for a while now. Wow, I learned again new things: alt + F2 plus the "r" command to reload, plus it fixed the keyboard issue. Grazie.